# Jquery to allow checkbox after checking a condition?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, checkbox, conditional-statements

I have 3 checkboxes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75yrW.png)

by default 3 checkboxes are `False`
Now my requirement is that
`Both` option is allowed to be True only when both `First` and `Second` option is true
if any of them is false then `both` option should be unchecked i.e., `false`

I wanted to acheciver this with Jquery

so my jquery is:

```
    <input id="#first" type="checkbox" asp-for="first" /> 
    <input id="#second" type="checkbox" asp-for="second" /> 
    <input id="#both" type="checkbox" asp-for="both" /> 
        <script>
                function change() {
                    var firstArg = ($("#first").prop('checked')==true);
                    var secondArg = ($("#second").prop('checked') == true);
                    console.log("---" + firstArg + "------" + secondArg);
                    if (!(firstArg && secondArg))
                    {
                        $("both").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                }
    function activate() 
{
    change();
    $("#first").bind('change', change());
    $("#second").bind('change', change());
    $("#change").bind('change', change());
    
    }
    
    </script>
```

But it is not working, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: for starters: html id's should not contain '#'

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "`Both` option is _*allowed*_ to be True" as there is difference between an element being checked (true/false) versus disabled (not accepting user input)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  const $cb1 = $("#first");
  const $cb2 = $("#second");
  const $cb3 = $("#both");

  $cb3.prop('disabled', !($cb1[0].checked && $cb2[0].checked));

  $("#first, #second").click(function(event) {
    $cb3.prop('disabled', !($cb1[0].checked && $cb2[0].checked));
  });

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- id's should not contain #:  id="#first" is incorrect -->
<label><input id="first" type="checkbox" asp-for="first" />First</label>
<label><input id="second" type="checkbox" asp-for="second" />Second</label>
<label><input id="both" type="checkbox" asp-for="both" />Both</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

```
<p>
    <input id="first" type="checkbox" asp-for="first" onchange="check()" />
    <label for="first"><b>First</b></label>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="second" type="checkbox" asp-for="second" onchange="check()" /> 
    <label for="second"><b>Second</b></label>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="both" type="checkbox" asp-for="both" /> 
    <label for="both"><b>Both</b></label>
</p>
```

js:

```
function check() {
            var firstArg = $("#first").prop('checked');
            var secondArg = $("#second").prop('checked');
            if (firstArg&&secondArg) {
                $("#both").prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $("#both").prop('checked', false);
                $("#both").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            check();
        });
```

result:

[image]